# Problema ao passar parâmetro via GET MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Não consigo pegar os valores por `GET` dentro de um *controller* ou *action*, exemplo:

**Não funciona:**

```
example.com/controller/?q=nome
example.com/controller/action/?q=nome
```

**Funciona:**

```
example.com/?q=nome
```

**OBS: parâmetros do tipo POST funcionam normalmente**

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar um exemplo do código PHP onde você tenta pegar os valores via GET?

Comment: Eu coloco algo do tipo $test = $_GET['query'] no meu controller e depois passo ele pra minha view.

Comment: então, mas se você está usando `?q=nome` na url, tente usar `$_GET['q']` no código...

Comment: Foi só um exemplo, mas não funciona

Comment: Url = $1 porquê usar q no parametro do link solicitado ?

Answer (score 1):

Está acontecendo o seguinte:

```
index.php?url=/controller/action/
```

então a sua `$_GET['url']` vem preenchida com esse endereço `url=/controller/action/` !!!

Para recuperar de modo efetivo utilize `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` que o mesmo vai trazer: `/controller/action/?q=nome`.

Pronto agora é só trabalhar com rotinas esse valor:

***1) Exemplo simples:***

```
$url = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']: '';
if ($url != ''){
    $urls  = explode('/', $url);
    $param = str_replace('?','', end($urls));
    $param = explode('&', $param);
    $params = array();
    foreach($param as $pa){
        $vp = explode('=', $pa);            
        $params[$vp[0]] = sizeof($vp)==2?$vp[1]:NULL;
    }
    //só para imprimir valor na tela!!! var_dump
    var_dump($params);
}
```

*Resultado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

***2) Exemplo com*** [**parse_url**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
var_dump(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

*Resultado:*

```
array(2) { ["path"]=> string(19) "/controller/action/" ["query"]=> string(6) "q=nome" }
```

*Referência*

- [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Obrigado, entendi como funciona, dei uma fuçada aqui no stack e encontrei a função parse_str, e fiz isso:

`$url = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '';

 $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
 parse_str($query, $param);

 return isset($param[$param_name]) ?        $param[$param_name] : null;`

Comment: Verdade @user3386417, tinha me esquecido dessa função ..., já editei para que fica para todo o pessoal!